# Derivatives of Eisenstein series

Tags: nt.number-theory, automorphic-forms, eisenstein-series

A book of Moeglin-Waldspurger says that there was a conjecture that every automorphic form arises as the derivative of an Eisenstein series which is proved there for function field case and proved by Franke in his famous paper for number field case. Can one suggest a reason why one should believe such conjecture a priori?

Comment: I am no expert, but it seems like Langlands, "On the notion of an automorphic representation" proved that every irreducible automorphic representation appears as the representation generated by some coefficient in the Laurent series expansion of an Eisenstein series. This allows residues (and other poles) of Eisenstein series, not just derivatives.

Comment: Is there a simpler statement for the $GL_2(\Bbb{Q})$ case ?